# How can I correct/alter/change the workspace path in my environment settings?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, environment-variable

This has been bothering me for a very long time.  No matter what I do, whenever I open ArcGIS Desktop, the environment settings for current and scratch workspaces revert to a path that is non-existent on my computer.

[image]

The blurred portion of the path, should be my username, but it is someone else's username.  If I change this, it reverts back when I reopen ArcGIS.  I'm trying to determine if there is a file somewhere (perhaps an xml file) which stores these default settings.  I tried deleting the normal.mxt file thinking that was the culprit, but to no avail.

It is getting very frustrating because whenever I try to run a tool, it defaults to this location and I have to change it manually.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1 and Windows 7, 64-bit.

I'd prefer not reinstalling Arc, but I'm open to it if that is the only way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out.

### Solution:

Open ArcCatalog.  Go to GeoProcessing... Environments...
Set the correct workspace paths.

Open ArcMap.

It should now work.

Answer (score 3):

Without opening ArcCatalog, you can also go to the Catalog window of ArcMap and choose Options at top right and set your Home Folder Path:

[image]

Then closing and re-opening ArcMap to check the Environment Settings shows that they have been altered:

[image]

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: @Fezter That's odd because I just tested it and it worked for me.  I've added a little more detail into my answer.

Comment: My home folder was set correctly yet the workspaces didn't change.

Comment: I wonder if you did not close/re-open ArcMap in between.  I omitted that key detail in my original answer.

Comment: I can't recall. In any event it's fixed now anyway. Thanks for the effort.